# how to use SIOCIFDESTROY in FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, ioctl, ifconfig, tun-tap

My app creates a tap interface, and everything works well.  But on FreeBSD, when it exits, the tap interface remains.  To delete it, I have to manually run this command:

```
sudo ifconfig tap0 destroy
```

But I'd like to do this programmatically within my application.  Where can I find the docs for SIOCIFDESTROY?  Here is what I've tried when my app exits:

```
struct ifreq ifr;
memset(&ifr, '\0', sizeof(ifr));
strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "tap0");
int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
err = ioctl(sock, SIOCIFDESTROY, &ifr);
```

At this point, err is zero, but the tap interface still exists when the app ends.  Anyone know what else I might be missing?

Comment: Nevermind...!  Of all the things I tried, this exact code I pasted in my question is what _did_ work.  I just hadn't noticed I'd found the solution because of all the previously-created TAP interfaces.  Not sure what to do with this question.  Feel free to close, or leave open for any future developers looking to use SIOCIFDESTROY.

Comment: You might want to answer the question - and repeat the working code - and explain what was happening. This seems valuable and that way the question (probably) won't be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tricky part was trying to find documentation to describe is the parameter to pass to ioctl().  I never did find anything decent to read.

Turns out a completely blank ifreq with just the tap interface name set is all that is needed.  In addition to the original code I included in the question, also note that I close the tap device file descriptor prior to deleting the actual tap interface.  I can only imagine that might also be relevant:

```
    close(device_fd);
    struct ifreq ifr;
    memset(&ifr, '\0', sizeof(ifr));
    strcpy(ifr.ifr_name, "tap0");
    int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    err = ioctl(sock, SIOCIFDESTROY, &ifr);
```